# How do I implement multiple cell selection for LazyVGrid?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI, how do I implement something like the multi-image selection gesture using SwiftUI? Single tap is no problem, but for multi-image selection I probably need a DragGesture. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to hit test or to determine what view is below my finger.

I am using a `LazyVgrid` and trying to do everything in SwiftUI. I am trying to implement functionality similar to Multiple Selection available in UIKit's `UICollectionView`

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue.